# Change webpack DefinePlugin value based on Webpack build context

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using Webpack's [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), is it possible to change the value of a key based on the Webpack build context? Such as entry name, output details, etc.

For example:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: "main.js",
    "main-free": "main.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      FREE_VERSION: (ctx) => ctx.entryName.endsWith("-free"),
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: `[name].js`,
  },
};
```

```js
// main.js

if (FREE_VERSION) {
  alert("You're using a free version.");
} else {
  alert("Thank you for purchasing.");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with the DefinePlugin, but you might be able to get around it by exporting an array of configs:

```
function getConfig(entryKey, entryValue, isFree) {
  return {
    entry: {
      [entryKey]: entryValue
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        FREE_VERSION: isFree,
      }),
    ],
    output: {
      filename: `[name].js`,
    },
  }
};

module.exports = [
  getConfig("main", "main.js", false),
  getConfig("main-free", "main.js", true),
];
```

Comment: That's a great idea! Will give it a try